# Magento2 how to use foreach in email templates to send multiple items and customers information?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

I want to send custom email.In that i have to display multiple customers and customers cart items.For that I have created a custom module.In that I have written model to get all the needed data.How can I display the multiple items and multiple customers information in the email template.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To use loop in email templates you need to use a default Magento block.

```
{{block
class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template'
template='VendorName_ModuleName::email/some-template.phtml'
area='frontend'
customers=$customers
}}
```

In the created template file you may use the php foreach.

```
<?php foreach ($block->getData('customers') as $customer): ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($customer->getFirstname()) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```